# Get current tasks of VirtualMachine with pyvmomi

Tags: python, vmware, pyvmomi

I'm trying to get all the current tasks of a VirtualMachine and check if they are all 'Completed' before continuing.

Using python2.7 on vmware 6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. 
You can use recentTask.
[Doc here](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/6b586ed2-655c-49d9-9029-bc416323cb22/fa0b429a-a695-4c11-b7d2-2cbc284049dc/doc/vim.ManagedEntity.html#recentTask)